# Get User location and Convert into human readable address

Tags: google-maps

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) link to get users lat-longs.To convert these lat-longs I have used google address reverse geocoding i.e Geocoder class and geocode method([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)). Now I have a concern that can I use these two things together.

Are there any restrictions on using them together for commercial purpose are there any limits or things I will need to follow.
As I am new to consume google map services, I need some help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve your users location, that's coming from your browser apis. Thats not a google call.

When it comes to geocoding, there are limits for private users (2500 geocoding requests per day) + commercial (100000 per day).

But its OK to use both services together. 
I'd like to ask you to take a look in the FAQs

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#usagelimits